# How to make a dynamic generic?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I'm trying to write a protocol that allows me to version models in my app. In order to do that I wrote the following `VersionManager`.

```
class VersionManager<Type: Decodable> {
    private var database: Database

    init(database: Database) {
        self.database = database
    }

    var versions: [Type] {
        return []
    }
}
```

After that I wrote a protocol that I can add to models:

```
protocol Versionable {

}

extension Versionable {
    private var manager: VersionManager<Restaurant> {
        return VersionManager<Restaurant>(database: Database.shared)
    }

    public var versions: [Restaurant] {
        return manager.versions
    }
}
```

Now, the problem I'm facing is that I tried passing the type dynamically instead of hardcoded, like I have now for `Restaurant`.

So I tried changing the protocol to this:

```
protocol Versionable {
    var kind: Decodable.Type { get }
}
```

Then I wanted to pass `kind` to `VersionManager`. However, when I try that Xcode throws this error: `Expected '>' to complete generic argument list`.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What is this extension to the `Versionable` protocol?

Comment: It implements two variables that the models implementing `Versionable` get for free.

Comment: But protocol doesn't implement anything or am I missing something here?

Comment: I left out some other stuff that it implements, because it's unrelated to the question.

Comment: A typo on my part, I meant to write  _a protocol_ in a more general sense. So what I am trying to say that protocol defines function and property types but you use a class or struct for the implementation. I tried to find a solution for your problem but I was very confused by the protocol extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use generics inside a `protocol`, you need to use an `associatedtype`

```swift
protocol Versionable {
    associatedtype Model: Decodable
}

extension Versionable {
    private var manager: VersionManager<Model> {
        return VersionManager<Model>(database: Database.shared)
    }

    public var versions: [Model] {
        return manager.versions
    }
}
```

The model that is going to implement the `Versionable` protocol will have to resolve this type:

```swift
struct SomeModel: Versionable {
    typealias Model = Int
}

SomeModel().versions // [Int]
```

I'm guessing `Restaurant` in your example refers to the model that implements `Versionable`. In that case, you can just use the `Self` reference inside your protocol extension:

```swift
protocol Versionable: Decodable {
}

extension Versionable {
    private var manager: VersionManager<Self> {
        return VersionManager<Self>(database: Database.shared)
    }

    public var versions: [Self] {
        return manager.versions
    }
}

struct SomeModel: Versionable {}
SomeModel().versions // [SomeModel]
```

Please note that the `Versionable` protocol now requires the `Decodable` conformance because of the `VersionManager<Type: Decodable>` generic constraint.